# Remove space between element and class

Tags: css, sass

I have the following:

```css
div {
   .demo {
      color: #000;
   }
}
```

Which Outputs:

```css
div .demo { color: #000; }
```

However, I need it to output without the space between the element and the class:

```css
div.demo { color: #000; }
```

Is there any way to do this using SASS Nesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use `&` to combine a selector with its parent:](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

```css
div {
   &.demo {
      color: #000;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning how to navigate their documentation. It's oddly structured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ampersand in front of .demo to achieve this.

```
div {
   &.demo {
       color: #000;
   }
}
```

The ampersand character is a placeholder for whatever the parent element is.